# how to get acknowledgement when audio is finished?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, audiotoolbox

I am playing audio in my application using audioPlayer.Play()

and it is play correctly.

i can not find when audio finish. i want delegate method when audio finished.

can you please write method when audio finished?

Comment: r u using MPMoviePlayerController?

Comment: check this link might be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27805657/swift-avplayer-how-to-track-when-song-finished-playing

Comment: - (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag;
for avaudioplayer

Comment: no i am not using MPMoviePlayer i simply used audiotoolbox

Comment: see answer below, may be that is what you trying to archive@imjaydeep

Comment: yes it is worked thanks!!

Comment: great! you are welcome@imjaydeep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be it is not possible with `audiotoolbox` framework, but what you can try is `AVAudioPlayer`.

just try following after adding:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

then use delegate method below to handle anything when audio finishes playing:

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag {
   // Audio finished playing
   //handle anything here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

set delegate to self

```
[myAudioPlayer setDelegate:self];
```

and then implement

```
    -(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
  /*Handle Code here*/
}
```